# How do I use a mean and 95% confidence intervals to draw from a distribution?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

I have a number of parameters for a model.  The parameter values are presented as the mean and the 95% confidence interval. I am not provided with standard deviation or sample size.

I am using R. I would like to sample an estimate for each parameter, similarly to using
rnorm(n, mean, sd) to draw from a normal distribution, so that with each simulation of the model the parameters values are slightly different.

How can I use the information provided (mean and 95% CI) to accomplish this?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: As in your previous question, you still need the sample size. There is a fundamental difference between confidence intervals and standard error on the one hand and the standard deviation on the other hand. Both the width of CI and the SE converge towards 0 as N gets large because you are getting increasingly precise estimates of the true mean. The (sample) SD does not, it converge to the true standard deviation of the distribution. It doesn't matter how many people (or trees) you observe, they are not getting more similar to each other just because you know more about them.

Comment: If your confidence intervals were constructed in the way $\bar{x} \pm 1.96SE$, you could retreive the standard error $SE=(\bar{x}-upper)/1.96$, but as @GaëlLaurans says, without any more information, you cannot estimate the standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

The confidence interval is calculated by: $$\mu\pm1.96*\sigma/\sqrt{n}$$

Without $n$ (the sample size) I don't think you can solve this. Although you could just guess the sample size and work from there.

The R-code is just:

```
sd <- (upper_ci - lower_ci)*sqrt(n)/1.96
```

Comment: Jup, but he doesn't have the sample size nor the standard deviation.

Comment: @COOLSerdash: You could loop through a set of theoretical sample sizes like c(50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 10000) and you could get an idea of how it impacts your statistic.